# Bind model to modal partial view .NET MVC/Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Partial View called `Details` which contains a button, that when clicked, surfaces another Partial View called `Edit`. Everything worked fine and I was able to send `Detail` data to `Edit` to well, be edited. Requirements have changed, however, and now the Partial View `Edit` needs to be surfaced in a modal. Now i'm unable to send the `Detail` object to the now `Edit` modal.

Controller method which launches `Edit` modal:

```
MyController.prototype.showEditModal = function (someObject) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.objectToBeEdited = {
        Id: someObject.Id,
        Name: someObject.Name,
        //etc...
    }

    var modal = myModal
        .open({
            templateUrl: "Edit",
            controller: MyController,
            controllerAs: "myCtrl",
            resolve: {
                objectToBeEdited: function () {
                    return angular.copy(ctrl.objectToBeEdited);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

`Edit` partial view:

```
<form name="frm" role="form" form-ext submit-ext="myCtrl.edit()">
    <h3>Edit - {{myCtrl.objectToBeEdited.Name}}</h3> <!--Name not rendered in H3 tag-->

    <div>
        <label for="id">Object ID</label>
        <!--Id not rendered inside input-->
        <input name="id" type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.objectToBeEdited.Id" required />
    </div>
    ...for brevity
</form>
```

It seems as though `objectToBeEdited` isn't being bound to `ng-model`. How do I send the model being surfaced in the `Detail` partial view to the `Edit` partial view modal?

Comment: instead of making a copy of `someObject` and passing the same, you can pass `someObject` itself to the modal..

Answer (score 0):

You can making a copy of `someObject` which is sent to the modal. This object wont be bound to the original object, you can try passing `someObject` itself to the Edit page. If you are doing so you can make a copy of `someObject` and keep as a backup, so that you can recover the original data if user presses cancel button in the modal.